# prove that a function is monotonically increasing

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

I want to show that the function

$ f(b)= \dfrac{2^a-2^b}{\ln(a)-\ln(b)}$

is an increasing function of $b \in [0,a)$, where $a$ is a real constant.

I have tried the following things:

1. To prove that the derivative of the function is positive. However, it is not obvious from the expression.
2. Plotted the function in matlab for a range of values of $a$. It is seen that the function is increasing.

Please let me know how to analytically show that the function is increasing in $b$.

Comment: have you tried comparing how quickly the numerator and the denominator increase with respect to each other? If you know their signs, knowing their individual rates might give you a clue

Comment: Note that $b \neq 0$. That is, $b \in (0,a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ f(b)= \frac{2^a-2^b}{\ln a-\ln b}$$

Then,
$$f'(b)=\frac{-2^b\ln 2(\ln a-\ln b)-(2^a-2^b)\cdot (-1/b)}{(\ln a-\ln b)^2}$$
$$=\frac{2^b}{b(\ln a-\ln b)^2}(-b\ln 2(\ln a-\ln b)+2^{a-b}-1)$$

Let $g(b)=-b\ln 2(\ln a-\ln b)+2^{a-b}-1$.

Then,
$$g'(b)=-\ln 2\ln a+\ln 2(\ln b+1)-2^{a-b}\ln 2=\ln 2(-\ln a+\ln b+1-2^{a-b})\lt 0$$
since $-\ln a+\ln b\lt 0$ and $1-2^{a-b}\lt 0$.

So, $g(b)$ is decreasing with $g(a)=0$, and so $g(b)\gt 0$ for $0\lt b\lt a$.

Therefore, since we have $f'(b)\gt 0$, we know that $f(b)$ is increasing.